# Save Excel worksheet as text file with name of worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to save the current worksheet of an Excel workbook with the name of the worksheet.  Based on an example from http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/textfiles.html.  I can save it with the name of the workbook (using Open (ThisWorkbook.FullName & ".txt") For Output As #nFileNum), but not the worksheet.  Tried ActiveSheet.Name, which will show in a msgBox, but it doesn't save.

```
    'from http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/textfiles.html
Public Sub FixedFieldTextFile()
    Const DELIMITER As String = "" 'Normally none
    Const PAD As String = " "   'or other character
    Dim vFieldArray As Variant
    Dim myRecord As Range
    Dim nFileNum As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sOut As String
    'MsgBox (ActiveSheet.Name)
    'vFieldArray contains field lengths, in characters, from field 1 to N
    vFieldArray = Array(30, 10, 10, 25, 25, 14, 14, 14, 14, 10, 10, 10, 10)
    nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open "Test.txt" For Output As #nFileNum
    'Open (ThisWorkbook.FullName & ".txt") For Output As #nFileNum
    'Open (ActiveSheet.Name & ".txt") For Output As #nFileNum
    'Open (Worksheet.Name & ".txt") For Output As #nFileNum
    For Each myRecord In Range("A1:A" & _
            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        With myRecord
            For i = 0 To UBound(vFieldArray)
                sOut = sOut & DELIMITER & Left(.Offset(0, i).Text & _
                        String(vFieldArray(i), PAD), vFieldArray(i))
            Next i
            Print #nFileNum, Mid(sOut, Len(DELIMITER) + 1)
            sOut = Empty
        End With
    Next myRecord
    Close #nFileNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming the current code works and produces Test.txt, and assuming the ActiveSheet's name does not contain any characters that are not valid as part of a file name, I can't see why `Open ActiveSheet.Name & ".txt" For Output As #nFileNum` wouldn't work (unless you were trying to use that statement **as well as** the `Open "Test.txt" For Output As #nFileNum` statement).  Are you getting any error messages?  Or does it just run but not produce anything?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.FullName` includes the full path, `Worksheet.Name` / `ActiveSheet.Name` do not.  Try `ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveSheet.Name & ".txt"`

Comment: chris neilsen - thanks, a life saver.  If you put this as an answer, I will accept it.